# Linq select data from 3 tables

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have the data base with these tables 
[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nJBd.png)

[image]

and I want to select the data from them which look like
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Xii.png)

[image]

But I can't select the Name which is FirstName+LastName from Emloyees table in my query. This is my code

```
from d in Skills
where d.SkillID == 5 or d.SkillID == 6 or d.SkillID == 7
select new
{
    Description = d.Description,
    Employees = from emp in d.EmployeeSkills
                select new 
                {
                    Level = emp.Level,
                    YearsExperience =emp.YearsOfExperience
                    Name = from na in emp.Employees
                    select new
                    {
                        na.FirstName + " " + na.LastName
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: You need a proper alias/property name for that: `Name = na.FirstName + " " + na.LastName`

Comment: What specifically isn't working with your code?  If you get an error what is it?  If the results are not what you expect then what are they?

Comment: @Silvermind: I tried it before but I got the error message :'LINQPad.User.EmployeeSkills' does not contain a definition for 'Employees' and no extension method 'Employees' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQPad.User.EmployeeSkills' could be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from d in Skills
where (d.SkillID == 5 || d.SkillID == 6 || d.SkillID == 7) // or is not supported
select new
{
    Description = d.Description,
    Employees = EmployeeSkills
            .Where(es => es.SkillID == d.SkillID)
            .Select(es => new 
            {
                Level = es.Level,
                YearsExperience = es.YearsOfExperience,
                Emp = Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeID == es.EmployeeID)                    
            })
            .Select(es => new 
            {
                Level = es.Level,
                YearsExperience = es.YearsExperience,
                Name = es.Emp.FirstName + " " + es.Emp.LastName))                    
            })           
}
```

Comment: Methods are not supported inside a l2s or l2ef query.

Comment: @serdar thanks for your answer. But your statement will select all Employee's name in employees table and show it in the result, not select the ones who actually have those 3 skills

Comment: @Kranatos you are right. Edited. (added '.Where(es => es.SkillID == d.SkillID)')

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the `Employee` information from the reference available in the `EmployeeSkills` entity and use the `Select()` method to define the result. You could use `let` keyword to define a sub-query and navigate between the references, for sample 9look the comments on the query):

```
// define the query
var query = from d in Skills

            // define a condition
            where d.SkillID == 5 or d.SkillID == 6 or d.SkillID == 7

            // define a value (in this case, a sub-query)
            let employees = d.EmployeeSkills.Select(x => new {
                                    Level = emp.Level,
                                    YearsExperience =emp.YearsOfExperience,
                                    Name = x.Employee.Name + " " + x.Employee.LastName                              
            })

            // define a result                
            select new
            {
               Description = d.Description,                 
               Employees = employees
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is there any way to do that in C# expression?

Comment: What do you mean "C# Expressions"?

Comment: I'm learning about Linq by using the LinQPad. And the C# expression is the one I can choose in the language tab

Comment: Linq is part of .Net and the code in my anwser, is written in C# language. I didn't realize what you say when "C# expressions" was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ's fluent API:

```
var result = Skills.Select(s => new {
    Description = s.Description,
    Employees = Employees
                .Where(e => EmployeeSkills.Where(es => es.SkillID == s.SkillID).Any(es => es.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID))
                .Select(e => new {
                    Name = String.Format("{0} {1}", e.FirstName, e.LastName),
                    Level = EmployeeSkills.Single(es => es.SkillID == s.SkillID && es.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID).Level,
                    YearsExperience = EmployeeSkills.Single(es => es.SkillID == s.SkillID && es.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID).YearsOfExperience
                })
});
```